# In a convex hexagon, Diagonal intersect at interior point of an hexagon.

Tags: probability

> In a convex hexagon two diagonal are drawn at random. The probability that the
>
> diagonal intersect at an interior point of an hexagon is

$\bf{Attempt}$ I have a doubt,

Diagonal of Convex hexagon always intersect at interior of an hexagon. So probability is $1$

But answer is given as $\displaystyle \frac{5}{12}$

Please clear my doubt., Thanks

Comment: I think you shouldn't consider a side (or its intersections) as an interior point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

I am considering that a vertex is not an interior point.

[image]

Consider just those black points as an interior point.

Remember that we have $9$ diagonals. Looking to the answer, the statement is 
also considering that any pair of diagonals have a intersection, even if it happens at an exterior.

Can you finish?